# spring integration: multiple step multiple channel subscribers

Tags: spring-integration

I have the need to implement an integration flow made of multiple steps, where each step can be performed by a variable number of processors (plugins).

What I have so far:

```
<!-- gateway -->
<int:gateway default-request-channel="step/1" service-interface="ServiceGateway">
    <int:method name="send" />
</int:gateway>


<!-- plugin 1 -->
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="step/1" apply-sequence="true" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="step/1" output-channel="step/2">
    <bean class="Transformer" />
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator input-channel="step/1" output-channel="step/2">
    <bean class="Transformer2" />
</int:service-activator>


<!-- plugin 2 -->
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="step/2" apply-sequence="true" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="step/2" output-channel="end">
    <bean class="Transformer3" />
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator input-channel="step/2" output-channel="end">
    <bean class="HttpTransformer4" />
</int:service-activator>

<!-- aggregation -->
<int:channel id="end" />
<int:aggregator input-channel="end" />
```

The expected behaviour is the following:

1. send the first request through the gateway
2. the input is processed by 2 "step/1" plugins
3. each output of the "step/1" plugins is processed by the "step/2" plugins
4. the aggregator should aggregate 4 items (1 -> 2 -> 4)

Everything is working fine but the result is not the expected, I receive only 2 (random) items instead of 4.

I suppose the problem is that the aggregator triggers the release after only two items because the "apply-sequence" in the "step/2" channel overwrites the "apply-sequence" in "step/1". So the question is: how can I make the aggregator wait for all the messages?

Thank you in advance.

Custom Release Strategy:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean canRelease ( MessageGroup group ) {

    MessageHeaders headers = group.getOne ().getHeaders ();
    List<List<Object>> sequenceDetails = (List<List<Object>>) headers.get ( "sequenceDetails" );
    System.out.println ( sequenceDetails );

    int expectedSize = 1;
    //map message id, max group size reached (i.e. sequenceNumber==sequenceSize)
    for ( List<Object> sequenceItem : sequenceDetails ) {
        if ( sequenceItem.get ( 1 ) != sequenceItem.get ( 2 ) ) {
            System.err.println ( "--> AGG: no release check, group max not reached" );
            return false;
        }
        expectedSize *= (int) sequenceItem.get ( 2 );//multiplies the group sizes
    }

    int expectedSize2 = expectedSize * (int) headers.get ( "sequenceSize" );

    int currentSize = group.getMessages ().size () * expectedSize;
    System.err.println ( "--> AGG: " + expectedSize2 + " : " + currentSize );
    boolean canRelease = expectedSize2 == currentSize;
    if ( canRelease ) {
        System.out.println ( "ok" );
    }
    return canRelease;
}
```

Prints out:

[[7099b583-55d4-87d3-4502-993f05bfb388, 1, 2]]

--> AGG: no release check, group max not reached

[[7099b583-55d4-87d3-4502-993f05bfb388, 1, 2]]

--> AGG: no release check, group max not reached

[[7099b583-55d4-87d3-4502-993f05bfb388, 2, 2]]

--> AGG: 4 : 2

[[7099b583-55d4-87d3-4502-993f05bfb388, 2, 2]]

--> AGG: 4 : 4

Aggregation code:

```
@Aggregator
public Object aggregate ( List<Message<?>> objects ) {

    List<Object> res = new ArrayList<> ();
    for ( Message<?> m : objects ) {
        res.add ( m.getPayload () );
        MessageHeaders headers2 = m.getHeaders ();
        System.out.println ( headers2.get ( "history" ) );
    }

    return res;
}
```

Prints out:

gateway2,core-channel,(inner bean)#57018165,async/step/1,core-channel,(inner bean)#57018165,async/step/2,core-channel,(inner bean)#57018165,end2

gateway2,core-channel,(inner bean)#57018165,async/step/1,core-channel,(inner bean)#57018165,async/step/2,core-channel,(inner bean)#57018165,end2

[102, 202] --> final result list, expected to be made of 4 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom release strategy. The correlation data from the first pubsub is pushed onto a stack in the `sequenceDetails` headers by the second pubsub.

**EDIT**

The problem is there are two groups; you need to correlate on the initial correlationId. Here's a pure SpEL solution; it might be safer to use custom correlation/release strategies to ensure the data is as expected (and use `getOne()` instead of the iterator)...

```
<int:aggregator input-channel="end2"
        correlation-strategy-expression=
           "headers['sequenceDetails'][0][0]"
        release-strategy-expression=
           "size() == iterator().next().headers['sequenceSize'] * iterator().next().headers['sequenceDetails'][0][2]" />
```

Comment: Hi Gary, I've implemented the custom ReleaseStrategy and now the release is triggered at the correct number of items in the sequence (4).
The problem is now that the output is still composed of 2 items.
Implementing a custom aggregator i've seen that even though the release strategy triggers the release at 4 items, the aggregation method (called correctly after 4 messages have passed through the canRelease method) receives a message list of 2 items (only one of the two produced groups).

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me; if the release strategy sees a group with 4 messages, you will get all 4 to aggregate. Your comment `only one of the two released groups` confuses me; there should be one group with 4 messages (the `sequenceSize` and `sequenceNumber` headers will be bogus though). Can you show your `ReleaseStrategy`? (Edit your question, don't try to paste it into a comment).

Comment: I added the two methods for release strategy and aggregation

Comment: This looks wrong `int currentSize = group.getMessages ().size () * expectedSize;` - I think you just need something like `return group.size() == sequenceSize * nestedSequenceSize`.

Comment: I posted the test code on [github](https://github.com/mcorallo/spring-integration-multi-pubsub)

Comment: The problem is there are actually 2 groups. See my edit.

Comment: Ok Gary, thank you very much, this points me in the right direction, I will work on the java code to make it work as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92462/discussion-between-max-and-gary-russell).

Comment: The chat function doesn't send notifications (at least for me). See my reply there.

Comment: Maybe my need is too specific, I'm implementing some kind of "pool of atomic plugins" that should be combined as needed. Putting an aggregator after each channel will force me to make the plugins take a Collection as argument, but I don't like this, I prefer the plugins to be free to take any Object as argument. Anyway, the final aggregator implemented with a loop on the sequenceDetails stack is working correctly. I will check if it's too heavy on the performance but it's a solution.